# How to use QNetworkManagerEnginePlugin?

Tags: linux, qt, networking, qt5, networkmanager

I want to create and remove interfaces from Qt. Also I want to connect to Wi-Fi by SSID using login and password. And many other things needed to manage internet connection on Linux.

To do this I prefer to stick the `network-manager` and `libnm-dev`. I found, that *Qt* has plugin here `qtbase/src/plugins/bearer/networkmanager/`. Seems it implements the needed functionality.

Also I am able to setup it in my *CMakeLists.txt*:

```
find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core DBus QNetworkManagerEnginePlugin)
qt5_use_modules(${PROJECT_NAME} LINK_PRIVATE Core DBus QNetworkManagerEnginePlugin)
```

In its sources directory it consists of just two header files and two corresponding `*.cpp` files (plus some from platform-dependent `../linux_common/*`). They exposes `QNetworkManager*` and `QNetworkManagerEngine` classes, which I want to use. But how to include them into my *cmake* project?

Comment: I accomplished that by doing the WiFi auth with NetworkManager DBUS API and then using QNetworkManager with SSID authenticated.

Comment: @AlexanderVX Do you mean `QNetworkAccessManager`?

Comment: First this: https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager and second this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html

Comment: And I am now replacing first with KDE Qt NetworkManager just because it is somewhat cleaner and I could not achieve certain things with DBUS. It is a wrapper over that same DBUS API: https://api.kde.org/frameworks-api/frameworks-apidocs/frameworks/networkmanager-qt/html/index.html